# How to reset state on submit button sreact redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have been struggling to reset the state on handleSubmit function. There are 3 questions that are coming one by one and on submit the next 3 questions should come like 1/3, 2/3 and 3/3 and this process goes on till all the questions are not submitted. Here is the code below:

```
const Quiz = () => {
    const { questions, quiz, options } = useSelector((state) => state.quiz);
    
    const [currentQuestion, setCurrentQuestion] = useState(0);
    console.log(currentQuestion[number] + "1q");
    
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const history = useHistory();
    const location = useLocation();
    const classes = useStyles();
    

    // this is to get the questions from the history coming from redux store.
    useEffect(() => {
        if (!questions) {
            dispatch(fetchQuestions(history));
        }
    }, []);

      const handleRadioChange = (number, event) => {
        let currentSelection = questions.find(question => question.number === number);
        console.log(currentSelection + "radio selected");
        currentSelection.value = event.target.value;
        console.log(currentSelection.value + "calculate score");
        // Set the new question count based on the current one
        setCurrentQuestion((current) => {
          return Math.min(
            current + 1,
            questions.length - 1
          );
        });
    };

    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
const valid = questions.some((q) => !q.value);
        console.log(valid + "questionsalpha");
        if (!valid) {
            dispatch(postQuiz({ responses: questions, id: quiz.id }, history));
        }
// this i added to get the question process repeat as earlier, but not working.
    setCurrentQuestion((current) => {
            return Math.min(
              current + 1,
              questions.length - 1
            );
          });
    };
    return (
        !questions?.length ? <CircularProgress /> : (
            <Grid className={classes.container} container alignItems="stretch" spacing={1}>
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    {/* Only show the question if it's index is less than or equal to the current question */}
                    {questions.map((question, index) => {return index <= currentQuestion ? (
                        <FormControl component="fieldset" key={question.number} className={classes.formControl} data-hidden={question.number !== current_question[question.number]}>
                            <FormLabel component="legend">{question.question}</FormLabel>
                            <RadioGroup aria-label="quiz" name="quiz" value={question.value} onChange={(e) => handleRadioChange(question.number, e)}>
                                {options.map((option) => 
                                    <FormControlLabel key={option.score} value={option.score} control={<Radio />} label={option.label} />
                               )}
                            </RadioGroup>
                        </FormControl>
                    ) : null})}
                    <Button type="submit" variant="outlined" color="primary" className={classes.button}>
                        Submit
                </Button>
                </form>
            </Grid>
        )
    );
};

export default Quiz;
```

As user submitted the form, the question should appear one by one and if user refresh the page in between it should show the same page where he lefts, not the new url.
Please help

Comment: @Tom please check this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `handleSubmit` should reset the state to 0:

````
const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const valid = questions.some((q) => !q.value);
    console.log(valid + "questionsalpha");
    if (!valid) {
        dispatch(postQuiz({ responses: questions, id: quiz.id }, history));
    }
    // Reset to zero, and let handleRadioChange increase it
    setCurrentQuestion(0);
};
    ```
````

Comment: One more thing @Tom when a page reloads it goes to the next url where score is shown without completing the questions and answers. Any idea why its happening?

Comment: You haven't shown anything to do with score or the whole page, so I'd have no way of knowing what is going on

Comment: its going to next page on page refresh instead of being on the same page. I think problem is with the setCurrentQuestion on handle button as in url its showing http://localhost:3000/quiz?quiz=2   (here second quiz its taking from RadioButon group name)

Comment: on relogin the user should be on quiz page if not completed but its redirected to last page. i think the problem is with questions.length may be this is not read. or some other, i am unable to figure out, i rmoved questions.length but still the same problem

Comment: I solved the issue. Thanks for being so kind and helping me out with the problem i faced.  useEffect(() => {
        if (!questions) {
            dispatch(fetchQuestions(history));
        }
    }, []);
in these line just removed empty brackets everything is working. Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71578420/previous-button-is-not-functioning-properly-react