# On page refresh the progress value becomes 0 and moves to the next page React Redux

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, react-redux, react-hooks

I want to save the progress in MongoDB and then display the progress. The progress value is getting calculated and updated. But when I do page refresh the progress value becomes 0 and in between moves to the next page.

```
const Quiz = (props) => {
   const {progress: lastProgress, userId} = props; 
    const [progress, setProgress] = useState(lastProgress || 0);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const history = useHistory();
  
    const classes = useStyles();
    

useEffect(() => {
    
          async function fetchProgress(){
            try{
          const progress = await api.get(paths.FETCH_USER);
          const newprogress = progress.progress;
          console.log(newprogress + "alpha");
          if (newprogress <= 100) {
            setProgress(Number(newprogress));
          }}
        catch(error){
          console.log(error);
        }
        };
          fetchProgress();
        }, []);
      
      
        useEffect(() => {
          async function updateProgress() {
            try {
              await api.patch(paths.UPDATE_USER, JSON.stringify({progress}))
                console.log(progress + "valueof");
            }
            catch(error){
              console.log("error", error);
            }
          };
          updateProgress();
        }, [progress]);
      
       function handleSubmit(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
             
            const valid = questions.some((q) => !q.value);
            console.log(valid + "questionsalpha");
            if (!valid) {
                dispatch(postAssessment({ responses: questions, id: assessment.id }, history));
            }
            setCurrentQuestion(0);
           setChecked((previousState) => !previousState);
           setTimeout(() => { 
            setChecked(previousState => ({
                 afterPreviousChange: previousState.previousChange
               }))
          }, 1000);
          setProgress((prevProgress)=> prevProgress + 10);  
        
        }
        return (
       <Grid item md={4} >
                <Fragment>
                  <Grid item xs={12} md={6} sm={6}>
                  <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}>
          <Box sx={{ width: '100%', mr: 1 }}>
                    <LinearProgress variant="determinate" orientation="vertical" value={progress} />
                    </Box>
                    </Box>
                  </Grid>
                </Fragment>
    
              </Grid>
              )
    );
```

I am able to calculate the value of progress and the value is stored but on page refresh the progress value changes to 0. Do not know what mistake I am making.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hey @Tanya if its not getting updated in the db you would have to include the functions that are responsible for handling this update on the backend ? Please include the backend file where this logic is happening so that we can see 

Also can you console log the payload of data the backend is receiving please so I can see the data structure

Comment: This update is happening from frontend. No backend is written for this particular section. This I am doing from frontend itself.  This logic is written in frontend only. I think the issue is in fetching the progress. @kodamace

Comment: @kodamace can you please help in finding the issue, i am able to update in db but its not getting fetched.?  I think the issue is the logic of fetch part. Thanks

Comment: @kodamace any other place to communicate?

Comment: What is the value of `lastProgress`? Can you clarify what "But when I do page refresh the progress value becomes 0 and in between moves to the next page" means? Can you walk us through the issue and what you are expecting the code to do?

Comment: value of lastProgress is  the value of the progress is page not refreshed but once the page is refreshed it becomes 0. I want on page refresh the value of progress remain and the page is also shown. As of now the page is not shown only the spinner is shown if page is refreshed @DrewReese

Comment: I meant to step us through each line of code in the question, starting with `lastProgress`, i.e. what it is and where it comes from.

Comment: @DrewReese I want that progress value with page data stays on page refresh.

Comment: lastProgress is the variable I have defined to get the value of progress bar last updated when user relogin or refresh the page @DrewReese

Comment: Ok, what if I just say what I think the issue is then? I think the component mounts and local `progress` state is `0`. Both `useEffect` hooks run. The second `useEffect` hook makes a PATCH request with progress `0` and updates whatever in the back end to 0. Sometime your frontend synchronizes.

Comment: @DrewReese can you provide me a solution for progressbar value to be stored in db. with increment of 10.

Comment: Are you just wanting to start *some* initial progress from the `handleSubmit` handler and setup an interval to poll for the current progress, and in the case of refreshing the page, grab any currently in progress processing in the backend and re-initialize the local progress state and reinstantiate the interval polling? (*presumably until progress hits 100?*)

Comment: I want when submit button is clicked the progress is increased by 10 and the progress value get stored in backend and when next submit button clicked its increased by 10 again and on page refresh or relogin the value of progress should be shown from where it is left at backend. Suppose user refreshes at 20, then when page reloads it must be from 20 and then increase till 100 @DrewReese

Comment: Yes what you wrote but the progress increases only on submit handler. @DrewReese

Comment: So `lastProgress` isn't used, it's irrelevant? The component only needs to retain/remember the last state value when it mounts? What is the condition for clearing progress?

Comment: For clearing the progress user has to answer 3 questions each time and when they submit the answers the progress increases.
I too think lastProgress is of no use. @DrewReese

Comment: @DrewReese but then how will be the progress value be fetched if not stored in any variable?

Comment: `progress` is the local state you are updating. I'm trying to figure out why you have two sources of truth. So far I've gathered you want to have some local progress state that is persisted and updated locally, and you want to also save the value to a backend DB. I guess what remains is how you decide to initialize the local state versus reload from some cache when you refresh the page, or how to invalidate the cache when the progressing is complete. Sounds like you need an additional chunk of "state" to say "track progress".

Comment: @DrewReese yes I need something like this.

Comment: @DrewReese i want to track the progress also, thats the main thing.

Comment: @Tanyamaheshwari can you log what const progress = await api.get(paths.FETCH_USER); this is please and give the log data details

Comment: It returns object, object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think all you need is to persist the `progress` state to longterm storage so it's accessible after a page reload. Use localStorage to persist the `progress` state when it updates. Lazy initialize the `progress` state from localStorage. This avoids any issue of accidentally "resetting" the progress back to 0 via the PATCH request.

Example:

```
const Quiz = (props) => {
  ... 
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(() => {
    return Number(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("progress")) ?? 0);
  });

  ...
    
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchProgress() {
      try {
        const { progress } = await api.get(paths.FETCH_USER);
        console.log(progress + "alpha");
        if (progress <= 100) {
          setProgress(Number(progress));
        }
      } catch(error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    };

    fetchProgress();
  }, []);
      
  useEffect(() => {
    async function updateProgress() {
      try {
        await api.patch(paths.UPDATE_USER, JSON.stringify({ progress }))
        console.log(progress + "valueof");
      } catch(error){
        console.log("error", error);
      }
    };

    updateProgress();
    localStorage.setItem("progress", JSON.stringify(progress));
  }, [progress]);
      
  function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    ...
    setProgress((progress) => progress + 10);  
  }

  ...
);
```

Comment: Thanks, I will check. One more thing can thi s be done without localStorage?

Comment: @Tanyamaheshwari Not really, you need to persist the React state *somewhere* so when the app is remounted you can repopulate it.

Comment: means the state persistence is needed for every step. As the data is saved in database but still on page loads why state reset automatically? Please check mail

Comment: I need help in one part of my code regarding the same, i have shown above, the state is getting lost on page refresh or relogin how to solve this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71509744/how-to-reset-state-on-submit-button-sreact-redux?noredirect=1&lq=1 @drewreese:

Comment: @Tanyamaheshwari Is that link correct? It's to a post a few weeks old and already answered.

Comment: Yes link is correct. Can you come on your gmail? There I can send you component, reducer and action. Issue is state lost during relogin and page refresh @DrewReese:

Comment: I have already mailed if you revert back I wil come to know the email id is correct then I can send you the code further

Comment: @Tanyamaheshwari Would a new question on SO be more practical? What state is being lost on page refresh or re-login?

Comment: Fine I will post a new question here. State is the loader starts rotating on page refresh or relogin

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71754480/on-page-refresh-or-relogin-the-state-gets-lost-react-redux   @drewreese:

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243619/discussion-between-tanya-maheshwari-and-drew-reese).